# Problem with media queries not working in css

Tags: css, media-queries

Hello i am having problems with media queries. I dont know what the problem is but looking at the colors it appears to not be working.

I am new to css but i tried to fix it by adding what is written below in my html document (after looking at other posts) however it does not seem to work still.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

Here is the code i have tried in my css document:

```
.newestpost {
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 400px;
    display: ;
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    margin: 30px 50px;

    @media screen and (min-width: 1312px) and (max-width: 3000px)   
    {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: ;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: Please **always post your included code as text**, not as images. Images may disappear, and even more importantly: you are now forcing people to re-type your code themselves in order to give suggestions on improving it.

Comment: sorry i did not think of that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A `@media` query should be a top level statement, that contains CSS rules. You can't nest it inside a CSS rule.

Change it to this, and see if it works:

```
.newestpost {
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 400px;
    display: ;
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    margin: 30px 50px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1312px) and (max-width: 3000px)   
{
    .newestpost {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: ;
    }
}
```

Comment: I believe if SASS is used, it supports writing media queries within a class.

Answer (score 1):

you should mention your css class in media. and you can't use @media inside of class...

```
.newestpost {
    line-height: 20px;
    height: 400px;
    display: ;
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    margin: 30px 50px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1312px) and (max-width: 3000px)  { 
   .newestpost {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to specify the class in the tag, where you need to apply the styling

<meta  **class="newestpost"** name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

```
.newestpost {
line-height: 20px;
height: 400px;
display: ;
width: 600px;
float: left;
margin: 30px 50px;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1312px) and (max-width: 3000px)   
{
    .newestpost {
        width: 100%;
        float: left;
        margin: ;
    }
}
```

Comment: [`<meta>`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/meta) is not a visible element

Comment: Yes, Agree @PeterB For example, where every they have implemented that styling. They need to use the same class name in the HTML tag

Comment: Indeed, but using `<meta>` to illustrate that is very much pointless. I am assuming they have put `class="newestpost"` already on a visual element where it would be useful. Putting a CSS class on a `<meta>` is by definition not useful.